# How to make a notification in Android that does not collapse itself?

Tags: android

The notification is now shown and hidden in the status bar after 2 seconds. How do I make the notification not go to the status bar?

```
     val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Over limit channel")
        .setContentTitle("")
        .setContentText("")
        .setGroupSummary(false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher_icon)
        .setContent(remoteViews)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setGroup("false")
        .setGroupSummary(false)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)

    val notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    notificationManager.notify(800, builder.build())
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick I found is to use the method `setFullScreenIntent(android.app.PendingIntent intent,boolean highPriority)` with this method the notification will never be removed from the status bar except when you do it yourself.

here is an example:

```
 val intent = Intent()

 val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

 val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "Over limit channel")
        .setContentTitle("")
        .setContentText("")
        .setGroupSummary(false)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.launcher_icon)
        .setContent(remoteViews)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setGroup("false")
        .setGroupSummary(false)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .setFullScreenIntent(pendingIntent,true)
```

From the android Studio documentation :

> An intent to launch instead of posting the notification to the status
> bar. Only for use with extremely high-priority notifications demanding
> the user's immediate attention, such as an incoming phone call or
> alarm clock that the user has explicitly set to a particular time. If
> this facility is used for something else, please give the user an
> option to turn it off and use a normal notification, as this can be
> extremely disruptive. On some platforms, the system UI may choose to
> display a heads-up notification, instead of launching this intent,
> while the user is using the device.
>
> Params: intent – The pending intent to launch. highPriority – Passing
> true will cause this notification to be sent even if other
> notifications are suppressed.

### UPDATE

For some API version for this to work you must add this permission on the manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it didn't help, the notification collapses to the status bar (

Comment: i have tested this code on android api 28 its work but not on api 30

Comment: @YuriPetrov which version you tested this code ?

Comment: I tested this code has function on api 28 24 23 but not on api 29 30 and 22

Comment: @YuriPetrov please check my answer i updated and now it's work on api 29 and 30

Comment: Thank you very much, everything worked out, you helped me a lot. !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can start a foreground service with your required notification, or you can set the notification as an onGoing event to make it non dismissible

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't need a permanent notification, I need a regular notification that doesn't collapse on its own.

Comment: if using onGoing the user will not be able to swipe the app from the action center.